# Python equivalence operator not working the way I expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

I have a Python script that assigns command-line arguments to different variables when the script is run from the command-line. I've done this before with little to no problems, but this time I'm getting hung up on what appears to be a little technicality, which I can't get around easily.

Let's say that I have the following statement near the beginining:

```
n_value = sys.argv[3]
```

The command-line argument I'm expecting is a string of an integer, 1 thru 6. Then, later on, I want to test the value that n_value points to in order to decide what way to go next. So, I have the following:

```
if n_value == "1":
    (do something)
```

At the end, there's an else statement for instances where the command-line argument input was not expected. I get this every time I try to run the program. I've tried changing the if statement to say things like:

```
if n_value == 1:
```

Or:

```
if n_value is "1"
```

Etc. I've tried a bunch of things, but I can't seem to make that value true.

I've also tried using pdb, with set_trace() before these statements. Within the debugger, I tried looking at the value of the expression n_value == "1" and it says "True". This leads me to believe that it might be some technical issue with the version I'm using (i.e., I'm doing something wrong and I don't realize it) or I just don't understand the ins and outs of Python equivalence operations.

Last note: The Python versions I've been using are 2.6 and 2.7. Same issue with both, as far as I can tell.

If interested, see the beginning of my main() method below:

```
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print(r'usage: python(2.6) ./log_likelihood_ngrams.py /path/to/input_file1 /path/to/input_file2 n_value')
        sys.exit(1)

    # Store command-line arguments as variables
    input_file1_path = sys.argv[1]
    input_file2_path = sys.argv[2]
    n_value = sys.argv[3]

    # Tokenize the input files and save their n-grams in n-gram-lists

    # For 1-grams
    if n_value == '1':
        ngrams_list1 = tokenize(input_file1_path)
        ngrams_list2 = tokenize(input_file2_path)
    # For 2-grams
    if n_value == '2':
        ngrams_list1 = bigram_list(input_file1_path)
        ngrams_list2 = bigram_list(input_file2_path)
    # For 3-grams
    if n_value == '3':
        ngrams_list1 = trigram_list(input_file1_path)
        ngrams_list2 = trigram_list(input_file2_path)
    # For 4-grams
    if n_value == '4':
        ngrams_list1 = four_gram_list(input_file1_path)
    ngrams_list2 = four_gram_list(input_file2_path)
    # For 5-grams
    if n_value == '5':
        ngrams_list1 = five_gram_list(input_file1_path)
        ngrams_list2 = five_gram_list(input_file2_path)
    # For 6-grams
    if n_value == '6':
        ngrams_list1 = six_gram_list(input_file1_path)
        ngrams_list2 = six_gram_list(input_file2_path)
    # If n is invalid, print an error message and exit the program.
    else:
        sys.stderr.write('\n\nThe value of n you entered is not valid!\nPlease enter a value between 1 and 6, inclusive.\n')
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Have you checked whether you're trying to compare different encodings?
Also, have you tried str(1)?

Comment: Print `repr(nvalue)`. That will reveal the answer :-)

Comment: @VikramSaran Yes, I have. I tried to change the initial assignment to n_value = str(sys.argv[3]) and n_value = sys.argv followed by n_value = str(n_value) (just because I've experienced issues with typecasting the actual sys.argv method before). I've also tried typecasting with int() and changing the values to actual integers, rather than strings of those integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an `elif` chain. What you have is a sequence of `if` statements; thus, even if the `if n_value == '1'` check passes, all the other checks will still run. When `if n_value == '6'` fails, the attached `else` will run, which you don't want. Use `elif`:

```
if n_value == '1':
    ...
elif n_value == '2':
    ...
...
else:
    whatever
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @user2357112 I can't believe I overlooked that! Will check now to see if that was the problem.

Comment: Yes, it works now. Thanks a lot. I thought I was going insane, trying out all these different ways of seeing if two things were equivalent. It didn't even occur to me to look at the rest of the if statement structure because I was testing the first if first and I figured it shouldn't get past that point.

Answer (score 1):

All the `if` statements after `if n_value == '1'` should be `elif` (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).

E.g.

```
if n_value == '1':
    # For 1-grams
    ngrams_list1 = tokenize(input_file1_path)
    ngrams_list2 = tokenize(input_file2_path)
elif n_value == '2':
    # For 2-grams
    ngrams_list1 = bigram_list(input_file1_path)

... etc ...

else:
    sys.stderr.write('\n\nThe value of n you entered is not valid!\nPlease enter a value between 1 and 6, inclusive.\n')
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Same to you @Warren Weckesser. (i.e., the message above)